# Can I increase the size of the processor L1 and L2 caches?

Tags: ram

Im running an Ubuntu server 12.04 and checked my CPU status with `lscpu` and got result:

```
L1d cache: 32k
L1i cache: 32k
L2 cache: 6144k
```

How can increase my Cache size?

Comment: Those cache memories are hardware design specific (they are real hardware, not just software setting which could be changed)

Comment: I forgot to mention that my server is a VPS. dos it matter?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know in VPS if cmd will return the real CPU info. Could you ask Web-E. (drop him a comment under his answer)

Comment: If the VPS is capable of reporting on-die cache sizes at all, and they aren't something crazy like 0 bytes, it is *probably* reporting the actual ones from the processor.  Doesn't change that these cache sizes really aren't that relevant to the end user.

Answer (score 8):

L1 and L2 cache are hardware cache. [lscpu](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/lscpu/) shows your hardware information. It will only increase if you buy a processor with higher cache size.